Lua Macros Second keyboard not disabled
I recently created script in Lua Macros.
It is supposed to disable second keyboard but it does not which in some programs result in shortcuts not working properly.
This is the code.
lmc_assign_keyboard('MACROS');
lmc_print_devices()

lmc_set_handler('MACROS',function(button,direction)
    if (direction == 1) then return end
    lmc_minimize()
    print(button)

    if (button == 27) then  -- ESC
        lmc_send_keys('^{Num0}',50)
    elseif (button == 112) then -- F1
        lmc_send_keys('^{NUM1}',50)
    elseif (button == 113) then  -- F2
        lmc_send_keys('^{NUM2}',50)
    elseif (button == 114) then  -- F3
        lmc_send_keys('^{NUM3}',50)
    elseif (button == 115) then  -- F4
        lmc_send_keys('^{NUM4}',50)
    elseif (button == 116) then  -- F5
        lmc_send_keys('^{NUM5}',50)
    elseif (button == 117) then  -- F6
        lmc_send_keys('^{NUM6}',50)
    elseif (button == 118) then  -- F7
        lmc_send_keys('^{NUM7}',50)
  end
end
)

I tried researching the problem on other forums but found nothing
